# User Mapping на 2 разных серверах sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Доброго времени суток.**

Имеется mssql "сервер A" и "сервер B" (на отдельных машинах)

**Сервер A:**

На сервере A создана имя входа "TESTLOGIN" и базы данных "BD1, BD2 , BD3, BD4"

TESTLOGIN сопаставлен с базами "BD1, BD2 , BD3, BD4" в разделе "User Mapping"

**Сервер B:**

Имеются абсолютно аналогичные базы по структуре "BD1, BD2 , BD3, BD4"

Вопрос: Как сопоставить TESTLOGIN с базами "BD1, BD2 , BD3, BD4" которые находятся на сервере B ?

***p.s не смог понять как работает serverlinked и подходит ли оно под мои нужды. Прошу помощи у знатаков.***

Comment: Расшифруйте фразу "Как сопоставить TESTLOGIN с базами "BD1, BD2 , BD3, BD4" которые находятся на сервере B?". Что значит сопоставить логин с одного сервера с базами другого?